# How to shuffle multiple lines <tag> </tag> items in a text files or excel?

Tags: excel, random, editor, notepad++, multiline

I have been searching for hours and haven't found a solution to this.
I have a selection I want to randomize but it's separated into multiple lines.
I can find the solution no problem for a single line randomiser but I'm stumped on this one.

Thanks for looking

This is what I have presently

```
1a
1b
1c
1d
2a
2b
2c
2d
3a
3b
3c
3d
```

I would like to randomize based on the number keeping the order of the letter the same

Comment: You should post expected output also.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the `notepad++` tag:

Here you can find a script to randomize the order of all or the selected lines.

https://github.com/ethanpil/npp-randomizelines

It requires the Python Script plugin which is easily installed via the plugin manager.

Comment: To make this script work for me, I had to add this line: `from Npp import *`

Answer (score 0):

First check out [this tutorial](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/23/sort-in-random-order-excel-formulas/) about using [`RAND()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rand-HP005209229.aspx) to generate random numbers which you can then sort by.

If you want to keep the "a, b, c, d" sequence the same, but shuffle the number component, I would split this data into two columns. Add a third column which will be for your random numbers. Finally, sort the numerical column according to the generated random values using [`VLOOKUP()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx). In other words, leave the letter column as-is, creating a shuffled number column.

Finally, combine the numeric and letter columns with a fourth column using [`CONCATENATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-HP005209020.aspx) and remove the split columns and random numbers.